# Matlab script for a dynamical system

Tags: matlab

The code

```
 function hennonMap(a, b, xn, yn, upper)
 Xval = zeros(upper, 1);
 Yval = zeros(upper, 1);
 for i=1:upper
Xval(i) = xn;
Yval(i) = yn;
x  = yn + 1 - a*xn^2;
y  = b * xn;
xn = x;
yn = y;
end
end
```

Is giving me zeros, can anyone see why?

Comment: What are you hoping will happen?

Comment: What values do you give to a, b, xn, yn and upper?

Comment: @copper.hat generate some values corresponding to iterations of the map?

Comment: @MathFun123 I started with the standard $a=1.4$ $b=0.3$ and took the origin as inital value and $100$ iterations.

Comment: There are no outputs declared. What are you expecting the function to do? Print out some values at each iteration. Try something.

Comment: @copper.hat I tried calling "Xval" after running it.

Comment: You need to read the manual or start with simple examples. This is not a Matlab sponsored teaching site.

Comment: Xval is inside the function, so MATLAB doesn't remember it. If you want to gain information from a function, you have to return the information.

Comment: @MathFun123 it was all zeros which imo means that I must been saved, right?

Comment: @copper.hat cant you just ignore the question?

Comment: You are not paying any attention to the comments or my questions. How do you expect the function to do anything if you have no outputs?

Comment: @copper.hat I can explain. I was under the impression that the values "Xval" would be "saved" in "Xval" when runnig the function. Even if we are not asking it to print or declaring output. To me that is seperate things, but not to those who designed matlab apparently.

Comment: @copper.hat this is particularly illogical since it did return zeros, but that might have stemmed from some missclick from me before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function [Xval,Yval] = hennonMap(a, b, xn, yn, upper)
Xval = zeros(upper, 1);
Yval = zeros(upper, 1);
for i=1:upper
Xval(i) = xn;
Yval(i) = yn;
x  = yn + 1 - a*xn^2;
y  = b * xn;
xn = x;
yn = y;
end
end
```

Comment: thanks, I just skipped the function part instead then I got it to work. But now I understand the problem with the other one. Ill try this before taking this answer.

Comment: I do find it kind of odd that "Xval" returns zeros even if it didnt get "saved", if it didnt get saved it should just say "error" when calling it.

Comment: Yes I also don't know why, but does it work now?

Comment: yes it works fine now